# Crear un array de una lista de valores de google sheet y colocarla en una alerta

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito crear una alerta donde se muestre una lista de valores sin duplicados de una hoja de google sheet Valores: A, B, C, A, D, B

La alerta debe contener el siguiente array sin duplicados => [A, B, C, D].

Dispongo del siguiente código colocado en un html de google apps script

```
    /*GET DROPDOWN LIST */
    function getDropdownList(range){
    var list = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
    return list;
    }
  
  function createStateDropdown() {         
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(StateDropDown).getDropdownList("Country!A2:A7");    
  }

    function StateDropDown(values) { 
    var list = document.getElementById('State');   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
  
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text  = values[i];
      alert(option.text);
      list.appendChild(option);
         }
    }
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, gracias por tu interés. El problema es que alert(option. Text) no se abre como deseo... La alerta debe contener el siguiente array sin duplicados => [A, B, C, D]. Saludos

Comment: Agrega un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el objeto Set vas a poder obtener valores unicos. [Link referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```
  // set = El objeto Set le permite almacenar valores únicos de cualquier tipo,
  //       ya sea valores primitivos o referencias a objetos.

  const mySet1 = new Set()
  const arr = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B','E','E','E' ];

  arr.forEach( val => { 
     mySet1.add( val );
  });

  let arrValUnico = [...mySet1] ; 

  console.log( " arrValUnico = " + arrValUnico.join(",") );
   // resultado:   arrValUnico = A,B,C,D,E
```

Comment: Gracias @patrick. Me sirvió. Adapté tu aportación a mi código.